# How to change input length in Embedding layer for each batch?

Tags: keras

I am designing an embedding layer where the vocabulary is ~4000 and most training examples have a short length of less than 10. However some examples have a length of 100 or possibly even several hundred, and I would like to avoid zero padding every single example to length 100+ in order to maintain constant input length across all examples.

To remedy this I would like to only pad based on the max length *within the batch*, so that almost all batches would only have input length ~10 with only a few batches having a lot of padding. How do I load in each batch with a different input length into the Embedding layer?

Comment: Are you trying to do a batch training? I want to do a batch training using `fit_generator`, but I don't know how to do that when a model contain an embedding layer. How can I even compile a model when I don't know the parameters of the embedding (eg. input length)?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to set input_length argument to None. But if you are going to use Dense and Flatten layers after this layer, they might not work. For more visit [keras doc page](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/)

> ... This argument is
>   required if you are going to connect  Flatten then Dense layers
>   upstream (without it, the shape of the dense outputs cannot be
>   computed)

```
model = keras.models.Sequential(
    [
      keras.layers.Embedding(voc_size, embedding_dim, input_length=None)
    ]
)
```

Now the model can accept variable length sequences.

Comment: Can the variable input work with just Dense layers (i.e. not flatten)?

Comment: No, I'm afraid. It might even not work with LSTM when the return_sequences is False.